# Https request returning error in response 'certificate has expired' for shortswitch api

Tags: node.js, https, certificate

I am making a request to shortswitch api using https package of nodejs. It returns error 'certificate has expired' in response. Shortswitch doesn't have a client-side certificate that we can send with the request. They have a server-side certificate which is valid when verified through an SSL-checker.
I am using node version 6.14.0 (since the app is on production and running we can't update node version yet).

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Code snippet:

```
https.request('https://api.shortswitch.com/shorten?apiKey=****&longUrl=***********&format=json', function(res){
console.log("Connected");
res.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

});

[image]

Edit: I added the following cert as per suggested solution.

```
const ISRGCAs = [`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----`];


const options = {
host: 'api.shortswitch.com',
path: '/shorten?apiKey=***&longUrl=*****&format=json',
method: 'GET',
port: 443,
ca: ISRGCAs
}

https.request(options, function(res){
var data = [];

res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data.push(chunk);
    console.log((Buffer.concat(data)).toString());
});
res.on('end', function() {
    var buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
    console.log(buffer.toString());
});
```

});

but now getting error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API/server is not 'returning' expired; it is using a certificate/chain which *your nodejs client* is rejecting, because the cert is from LetsEncrypt which by default still uses a 'compatibility' root (DSTX3) that expired last Sept, but which *most* clients (including the sslchecker you used) can replace with the newer and still-valid ISRG root.

nodejs uses OpenSSL with by default its own hardcoded list of CA certs, which in nodejs 6 did not include the ISRG root; further, depending on your system and build, it *may* be using an older version of OpenSSL which doesn't do the replacement-with-new-root correctly. To solve this problem you must have recentish (>=1.1.0) OpenSSL *and* add the ISRG root; you can do the latter in code by setting the `ca` option, or with environment variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS.

See [Axios fails with 'certificate has expired' when certificate has not expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69400610/axios-fails-with-certificate-has-expired-when-certificate-has-not-expired)
[LetsEncrypt root certificate expiry breaks Azure Function Node application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69445796/letsencrypt-root-certificate-expiry-breaks-azure-function-node-application)
[Giving Axios LetsEncrypt's New Root Certificate On Old Version Of Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69414479/giving-axios-letsencrypts-new-root-certificate-on-old-version-of-node)

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but get timeout error

Comment: You connected okay (no cert or other SSL/TLS error) but didn't send a request. To actually send the request using `https.request` you must call `.end()` on that object; see https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/https.html#httpsrequesturl-options-callback . Or use `https.get()` which does this for you: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/https.html#httpsgeturl-options-callback . (Both are the same as the related/similar `http` API.)

Comment: I get 'socket hang up' error, in both cases using https.get() or calling req.end() for https.request().

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired result with your explanation using request module, so marking it as an answer but still I would like to discuss on how we can achieve it using https module?

Comment: PEM format (of a cert or anything else) REQUIRES linebreaks, but the string you show in your edit doesn't have them. However, when I pass such a malformed string for `ca` to `https.get` I don't get 'hang up', I get `Error: unable to get local issuer certificate` with a stacktrace. (And passing the correct ca string connects okay, but gets HTTP 500 response because I don't have a valid apikey.) I don't have time to look at `request` right now.